# Handling of kwargs keyword arguments in Django class-based views (CBVs)

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I just got dangerously close to madness when I (being a
Django beginner) failed to
access a model object by primary key `pk` (coming from the URL)
in my `FormView` subclass and tried to understand how to
do that *right*.
It's confusing.

**So how are keyword arguments passed around in generic CBVs and 
how should they be handled and used?**

(And I am going to answer myself, because I found it out and wrote it up
in order to understand it properly.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Don't confuse `kwargs` with those other `kwargs`...

- Remember that a **view** is eventually always a **function**.
  As you may remember from ["How Django processes a request"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request),
  unnamed groups from the urlconf regexp will be passed to the view as `*args`
  and named groups as `**kwargs`.
- But for a CBV it is less obvious what that view function actually
  is or what it does, because this is hidden deep within Django.
  As you may remember from ["Using class-based views"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views),
  a CBV's **`as_view()`** function will create and return the
  actual view function.
- So here is the first thing to remember about `kwargs` handling:
  In `urls.py`, when you write something like
  `MyView.as_view(myarg=myvalue)`,
  each such **keyword argument** will override the same-named **class attribute**
  of the CBV class in the CBV instance.
  Those arguments are together referred to as **`initkwargs`**.
- The view function that will **actually** be **executed** (let us call it **`vvv`**)
  is a generic one
  defined in [django.views.generic.base](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py).
  It **instantiates** your CBV, passing the `initkwargs` to the constructor,
  stores the `request`, `*args`, and `**kwargs` in same-named
  attributes in the CBV instance,
  and finally calls `dispatch()` on the instance.
- And here comes one of those confusing details:
  Those **same arguments** `request`, `*args`, and `**kwargs`
  will also **redundantly** be **passed to `dispatch()`** directly.
  (I write call parens to indicate methods as opposed to data attributes;
  empty parens do not mean there are no arguments.)
- **`dispatch()`** looks at the request and calls
  `get()`, `post()`, `head()` etc. depending on request type,
  again passing the arguments.
- And more redundancy is just around the corner:
  The `initkwargs` are redundantly stored in `vvv.view_initkwargs`.
  (Try to forget this quickly, you will rarely need it.)
- Once the thusly-created view is called, **the "real" `kwargs`
  are passed to various request handling methods** in the various
  generic view subclasses and view mixin classes.
  Those classes' structure, however, can drive you mad.
  Should you be interested in preserving your mental health,
  I strongly recommend using [`vanilla-views`](http://django-vanilla-views.org/)
  as a replacement for Django's built-in generic CBVs.
  The package provides the same capabilities in a vastly simpler form.

### To sum it up

There are
**(1)** `initkwargs` which stem from
individual keyword arguments to the `as_view()` view factory method
and will end up as
individual attributes of the CBV class instance
and
**(2)** `kwargs` that stem from
named groups in your urlconf instance
and end up as
**(2a)** keyword arguments to calls to your
`get()` and `post()` methods as well as as, confusingly,
**(2b)** an attribute `kwargs` in your CBV class instance.

So **which should you use**, the `kwargs` argument or the attribute?
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21384315/2810305)
argues that **using the attribute is more natural** for a CBV and
that it will also make your code more
uniform, because the argument is not available in all places
within the CBV framework.

And this is the final source of confusion:
Those methods to which the `kwargs` will *not* be passed often
nevertheless *do* have a `kwargs` parameter themselves...

### Moral

Prefer `self.kwargs` over the `kwargs` argument wherever possible and don't let `initkwargs` confuse you.

Comment: For we newbs, some code example help a Lot.